# Can I call Allah as God or Parwardigar or yahweh?

Tags: quran, hadith, allah, fiqh

Can I call Allah as God or Parwardigar? I can't locate the word parwardigar or yahweh in Quran and ahadith.

Comment: [Profaning the names of Allah](https://islamqa.info/en/130962) is not allowed in Islam. One can only call Allah by the names Allah had decreed. Names you cannot locate in Qur'an or hadith are not to be used.

Comment: Shaykh al-Islam Ibn Taymiyah (may Allah have mercy on him) said: The Lord, may He be glorified, may be referred to in Arabic as Allah, ar-Rahmaan (the Most Gracious), ar-Raheem (the Most Merciful), and in Farsi as Khoda and so on, but He, may He be glorified, is One, and there are many ways to refer to Him. End quote from al-Fataawa al-Kubra, 6/568

Comment: This is not an accurate translation. He used the word "describe" and he was talking about words that can be translated to describe Allah. If the question is about sefat and not asmaa', please clarify.

Comment: @III-AK-III what is the difference between "describe" and "refer to" in English? Maybe the translation is meant to mean "describe" by the words "refer"

Comment: @Kilise It is in the same fatwa on pp. 569-570 saying that "names in other languages may be perceived as attributes, and not that attributes in other languages may be perceived as names that can be used as _asma' hosna_." This is a very quick translation.